# Cannot select grid element through jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-selectors

This is a follow-up question to [ASP.NET How to pass container value as javascript argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591081/asp-net-how-to-pass-container-value-as-javascript-argument)

Darin Dimitrov has kindly provided [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591081/asp-net-how-to-pass-container-value-as-javascript-argument/1591160#1591160) using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), 
But for some reason, I was not able to *select* the grid row I wanted to.

Here is the jQuery used to select row.

```
$(function() {
    $('#_TrustGrid input[name^=trustDocIDTextBox]').each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert('Hello world = ' + index);
            setGridInEditMode(index);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the actual output HTML markup.

```
<input 
    id="_TrustGrid_ctl16_ctl05_ctl00_trustDocIDTextBox" 
    type="text" value="198327493" 
    name="_TrustGrid$ctl16$ctl05$ctl00$trustDocIDTextBox"/>
```

I have just started using jQuery tonight and been going through 
the official [jQuery Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) documentation but have been unsuccessful.

**Am I missing something here?**

Comment: @thanks, Nescio: Trying to solve one problem led me into jQuery just like that.  ;)  It's quite fun to learn this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why selecting through `#_TrustGrid` would not work.
I was able to get around the problem by specifying `:input` as shown below.

```
    $(function() {
        //$('#_TrustGrid input[id$=trustDocIDTextBox]').each(function(index) {
        $(':input[id$=trustDocIDTextBox]').each(function(index) {
            $(this).click(function() {
                alert('Hello world = ' + index);
                setGridInEditMode(index);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to save the full id of the control I used in my .aspx page:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       id="SubcontractorDropDownID" 
       value="<%= SubcontractorDropDown.ClientID %>" />
```

You can then just get the value of the id and then use that in your query to know which row to use.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I think you just want a '$' instead of '^' and you should be targeting the ID and not the NAME in your selector?

```
$(function() {
    $('#_TrustGrid input[id$=trustDocIDTextBox]').each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert('Hello world = ' + index);
            setGridInEditMode(index);
        });
    });
});
```